# Xdebug w/ PhpStorm

Tags: debugging

I'm using `drupal server` to use the built-in PHP server when building my Drupal 8 site.

I have xdebug set up and I'm using phpstorm. Both work.

The only small issue is that every time I start a debug session, it stops at the .console/router.php file. If I continue on, I get to my actual breakpoint. But I can't figure out how I can bypass this initial break that happens every time.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to PHPStorm - Settings

-> Languages & Frameworks

-> PHP

-> Debug

... Section "External connections" 
-> "Break at first line in PHP scripts" ... disable this option

Additional suggestion:

... Section "Xdebug"
-> disable the last two checkboxes

... Section "Advanced settings"
-> disable "Notify if debug session was finished without beeing paused"

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. You're my new favorite person. I upvoted your answer, but I don't have enough cred yet for it to show.